# How to change default sensor parameters in turtlebot3 (waffle)?

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am a ROS newbie. I am using the turtlebot3 packages to perform simulations in Gazebo/RViz. I am trying to make changes to the turtlebot3(waffle) sim sensors and see how it affects the simulation outcomes. Can anyone guide me on how to localize the specific files that have sensor parameters that can be modified? Is it possible to include all modifications in ONE launch file? It would be great to make changes to the distance sensor, camera, IMU, and odometry sensors. Perhaps, adding noise to those sensors would be great (if possible).  For clarification, is turtlebot3 (waffle) using a LiDAR sensor in Gazebo/RViz simulations?

I am performing my sim using Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.06 platform.

Thank you in advance!

-Jesus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317348/how-to-change-default-sensor-parameters-in-turtlebot3-(waffle)?/) by [jesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/40206/jesus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jesus,

In ROS robots are described using a [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf), normally stored with *.urdf* extention. That description may include the sensor/actuator models for Gazebo as well. Some times the URDF files are generated using a script  language named [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) (*.xacro* extension).

So what I would do to find the parameters passed to gazebo for any robot that I haven't worked with before is to find any *.urdf* and *.xacro* files inside of the robot's ROS packages.

If you have installed and compiled turtlebot3 packages from source code (https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3) you can go to your catkin workspace and execute the following command:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.urdf -o -iname \*.xacro \)
```

And then dig into any files listed on the output of the previous command.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1